# How can I group prices and sellers on Scrapy Python 3.6.4

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy Python and I would like to know the best way to group prices and sellers.

My code:

```
import scrapy
import re    
class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
     name = 'product'
     start_urls = ['https://www.google.nl/shopping/product/13481271230046931540?client=opera&biw=1880&bih=1008&output=search&q=738678181690&oq=738678181690&prds=hsec:online,paur:ClkAsKraX-dNyyNw1dQNKCoMJnN5PTCcIkKQRK_FTu38WNkh-ASATIAsHY2pgV1a1wnYh_rnqfve8FuuCsHc8boLnMjv9EO2Q4wJS_AvrOL1pcn-GYMYHecz7BIZAFPVH73OGQwGCep7aILTJXavWpXt0Ij80g&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmtKKLp5HaAhWHchQKHbO5Dg8Q2SsIFQ']
     all_seller = []
     def parse(self, response):
         self.log('Bla Bla Bla:' + response.url)
         for product in response.css(".os-main-table"):
             item ={
             "all_sellers": product.css(".os-seller-name-primary > a::text").extract(),
             "all_prices": product.css("td.os-total-col::text").re("\d+\,\d{1,2}"),
            }
         for item in zip(all_prices,all_sellers):
             scrapped_info = {
                 'all_sellers' : item[0],
                 'all_prices': item[1],
                 }
             yield scrapped_info
         next_page_url =  response.css('.pag-prev-next-links > a:last-child::attr(href)').extract_first()
         if next_page_url:
             next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
             yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
import scrapy
import re    
class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
     name = 'product'
     start_urls = ['https://www.google.nl/shopping/product/13481271230046931540?client=opera&biw=1880&bih=1008&output=search&q=738678181690&oq=738678181690&prds=hsec:online,paur:ClkAsKraX-dNyyNw1dQNKCoMJnN5PTCcIkKQRK_FTu38WNkh-ASATIAsHY2pgV1a1wnYh_rnqfve8FuuCsHc8boLnMjv9EO2Q4wJS_AvrOL1pcn-GYMYHecz7BIZAFPVH73OGQwGCep7aILTJXavWpXt0Ij80g&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmtKKLp5HaAhWHchQKHbO5Dg8Q2SsIFQ']
     def parse(self, response):
             all_sellers = response.css(".os-seller-name-primary > a::text").extract()
             all_prices = response.css("td.os-total-col::text").re("\d+\,\d{1,2}")
         for item in zip(all_prices,all_sellers):
             scrapped_info = {
                 'all_sellers' : item[0],
                 'all_prices': item[1],
                 }
             yield scrapped_info
         next_page_url =  response.css('.pag-prev-next-links > a:last-child::attr(href)').extract_first()
         if next_page_url:
             next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
             yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```